# How do I remove this JPanel from my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I will simplify this to what is in my program that is actually relevant to the question.

In one class I have this:

```
private void frame1(){

JFrame Introframe = new JFrame();
Introframe.add(new IntroText());

Introframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Introframe.setLocation(600,100);
Introframe.pack();
Introframe.setVisible(true);

}
```

In another class I have this

```
public class IntroText extends JPanel {

IntroText(){

setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 800));

}
```

So I am adding the JPanel from class IntroText into my JFrame.  But how do I remove it?!??!  I can remove all components with removeAll, but what if I don't want to remove all my components?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the variable `guy`?

Comment: oops im sorry that's not supposed to be there, that was from me messing around.

Comment: Use a CardLayout to help you swap components.

Comment: I'll check it out, though it'd just be nice if there was a simple way to do this.

Comment: @TravisBlack: a CardLayout **is** the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `JPanel` from it's parent:

```
Introframe.remove(introtext) // where introtext is an instance of IntroText
```

Although you wouldn't remove it as soon as you add it, here's an example:

```
private void frame1(){

JFrame Introframe = new JFrame();
IntroText introtext = new IntroText(); // your panel
Introframe.add(introtext); // add panel

Introframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Introframe.setLocation(600,100);
Introframe.pack();
Introframe.setVisible(true);

Introframe.remove(introtext); // remove it now

}
```

Comment: if I do Introframe.remove(IntroText());  then it says "cannot find symbol:method IntroText()".

Comment: Any time Travis. Let me know if you need anything else.